# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object line 52

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have seen numorous questions similar to this, however I still can't seem to resolve the problem, so sorry if this may be a duplicate.

Anyway here is the code:

```
$email = $_POST['emailAddress'];
$username = $_POST['userName'];
$dob = $_POST['dobYear'] . "-" . $_POST['dobMonth'] . "-" . $_POST['dobDay'];
$fname = $_POST['firstName'];
$sname = $_POST['lastName'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$squestion = $_POST['secretQuestion'];
$sanswer = $_POST['secretAnswer'];


require('db_connect.php');
$insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, salt, fname, sname, country, dob, squestion, sanswer) VALUES (:username, :email, :password, :salt, :fname, :sname, :country, :dob, :squestion, :sanswer)");
var_dump($mysqli->error);
$insert_stmt->bind_param(':username', $username); // error is here 
$insert_stmt->bind_param(':email', $email);
$insert_stmt->bind_param(':password', $password);
$insert_stmt->bind_param(':salt', $random_salt);
$insert_stmt->bind_param(':fname', $fname);
$insert_stmt->bind_param(':sname', $sname);
$insert_stmt->bind_param(':country', $country);
$insert_stmt->bind_param(':dob', $dob);
$insert_stmt->bind_param(':squestion', $squestion);     
$insert_stmt->bind_param(':sanswer', $sanswer);     
$insert_stmt->execute();
```

And this is the output of var_dump:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':username, :email, :password, :salt, :fname, :sname, :country, :dob, :squestion,' at line 1"

I know that there must be a problem on the prepare line but, I am really not seeing it.

Here is the db_connect.php just in case anyone wants to see though, this file is working fine:

```
define("HOST", "localhost"); // The host you want to connect to.
define("USER", "sec_user"); // The database username.
define("PASSWORD", "eKcGZr59zAa2BEWU"); // The database password. 
define("DATABASE", "secure_login"); // The database name.

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
```

Again, sorry if this is a duplicate or if I'm missing something blatent and obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class [`mysqli_stmt`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) does not support named SQL-parameters. Also, the first parameter to [`mysql_stmt::bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) is not the name of the SQL-parameter (because the class [`mysqli_stmt`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) does not support named SQL-parameters).

Comment: That's why it's a good idea to always read the documentation before using an unfamiliar API. The PHP documentation usually contains examples, too.

Comment: so what was the fix? I am having this EXACT issue... I am using the ?,?,? values

Comment: @jflay The fix is to make `$mysqli->prepare()` work. In the above question, `$mysqli->prepare()` failed because of the assumption that MySQLi understands named parameters. In your case, it fails for a different reason. Use the attributes of the [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) class to get more information about the reason.

Comment: yay I found it thanks to reading up on those class names... needed to stay consistent with the O-O approach and use bind_param() instead of bindParams or whatever the other php.net method was. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, salt, fname, sname, country, dob, squestion, sanswer) VALUES (?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

change your bind accordingly